# AES Encryption not the same result iOS and Android

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography, aes

I've been struggling for many days now finding out how to achieve a same result when encrypting plaintext password using AES.

I have codes below in Java (Android) and Objective-C (iOS). Honestly, the ideal result is the one produced by Java because our existing passwords are encrypted with this implementation.

Hopefully someone can pin-point my error for Objective-C. I am a super newbie on this programming language, so please bear with and don't be so hard on me. :)

Many thanks!

The plain text password is:

> 12345abc

### The Java code:

Encrypted text result is:

> BS/WyqmZ6AD68YbmFERn9w==

```
    private static String encryptionKey="ERVwiiYMFlDcZ0wp";
    private static String decryptionKey="ERVwiiYMFlDcZ0wp";
    JSONObject resultJSON=new JSONObject();
    private static byte[] initializationVector = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03,
        0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e,
        0x0f, 0x10 };

    public JSONObject encryptMethod(JSONObject jObject)
    {
        try {
            textToEncrypt = jObject.getString("text");      
            textToEncrypt = replaceSlashes(textToEncrypt);
            Log.d("STATE", "textToEncrypt: "+textToEncrypt);
            try {
                cipherText = encryptData(textToEncrypt);
        Log.d("STATE", "cipherText: "+cipherText);
                resultType=true;
                resultData=cipherText;
                resultMessage="Encryption success";
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resultMessage="Encryption is Not Possible, Please try some other text";
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resultMessage="Wrong Text Input, Please try again";
        }
        try {
            resultJSON.put("type", resultType);
            resultJSON.put("message", resultMessage);
            resultJSON.put("data", resultData);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJSON;      
    }

  public static String encryptData(String plainText) {


        String cipherText = null;
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        String skeySpecString = null;

        if (plainText == null || "".equals(plainText)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {       
            if(encryptionKey==null || encryptionKey.equals("")) {
                return null;
            }
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec ivps = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivps);
            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
            encryptedBytes = Base64.encode(encryptedBytes, 0);
            cipherText = new String(encryptedBytes);

        } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
            Log.e("Plain", "<===== BadPaddingException =====>", bpe);
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ibse) {
            Log.e("Plain", "<===== BadPaddingException =====>", ibse);
            return null;
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
            Log.e("Plain", "<===== InvalidAlgorithmParameterException =====>",
                    iape);
            return null;
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
            Log.e("Plain", "<===== InvalidKeyException =====>", ike);
            return null;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nae) {
            Log.e("Plain", "<===== NoSuchAlgorithmException =====>", nae);
            return null;
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
            Log.e("Plain", "<===== NoSuchPaddingException =====>", nspe);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Plain", "<===== Exception: {0} =====>", ex);
            return null;
        }
        return cipherText;
    }
```

### The Objective-C code:

Encrypted text result is:

> V+RZjcXVE+J1aG9kwt7CTA==

**Encrypt.m** file

```
-(NSString *) encryptData:(NSString *)plainText
{

    NSString *passphrase = @"ERVwiiYMFlDcZ0wp";
    NSData *key=[passphrase dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *password = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    StringEncryption *crypt = [[StringEncryption alloc] init];
    NSData *encryptedData = [crypt AES256EncryptWithKey:passphrase password:plainText];
    NSString *ciphertext =[encryptedData base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];

    return ciphertext;
}
```

**Crypt.m** file

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key password:(NSString *)plainText {

    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [plainText length];
    NSData *myData = [plainText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    const char myByteArray[] = {
                0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,
                0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,
                0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,
                0x0d,0x0e,0x0f,0x10 };

    NSData *vector = [NSData dataWithBytes: myByteArray length:16];

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          (__bridge const void *)(vector),
                                          myData.bytes, dataLength,
                                          buffer, bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Please check that in java "PKCS7Padding" is used as padding while in ios you are not using any padding.

Comment: @aBilal17 he does use `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` in `CCCrypt`

Comment: The funny thing is that neither implementation checks out under the openssl command line tool. The iOS version is closer, but must be decrypted in ECB mode, and then yields `e1 ba 64 3e 34 61 62 63  18 08 08 08 08 08 08 08` where the padding is correct except for one bit (18 --> 08) and the bytes indexed 4,5,6,7 are correct. Very strange. The Java one yields total garbage under openssl.

Comment: In all that testing, did you compare the binary key, IV and plaintext (using hexadecimal representation of the bytes)?

Comment: Hi @MaartenBodewes, I haven't tried that. I am completely not sure what to do, but let me do my research and get back to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @darkkean You are making one major mistake: You are misusing a string as key. byte representation of a String may be different in different languages. Therefore NEVER DO THIS! For tests use a hard-coded byte array. And if the final final software should use a password use PBKDF2 to derive a key from the password.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for pointing that out. However, I honestly lost how to do this on Objective-C but will do my research. If you have time, hopefully you can share a sample code for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705441/aes-encryption-android-ios-different-results-on-message-length-15-byte/19707532#19707532 for some ideas.